# Trying to search or install a package doesn't work and gives an error

Tags: atom-editor

When i try to search for a package or a theme i get this error message

> Searching for “package” failed. connect ETIMEDOUT
>   xx.xx.xxx.xx:xxx

But When i try to install a package or a theme if it the searched worked without a problem i get this error message

> Installing “package@ver” failed
>   Request for package information failed: connect ETIMEDOUT
>   xx.xx.xxx.xx:xxx (5 attempts) (ETIMEDOUT)
>
> Compiler tools not found Packages that depend on modules that contain
>   C/C++ code will fail to install. Read here for instructions on
>   installing Python and Visual Studio. Run apm install --check after
>   installing to test compiling a native module.

Comment: This could be a problem with your network. Do you have the ability to try downloading packages in another location, like school or library wifi?

Comment: @HollandWilson I can't check that since i don't use a Laptop nor Wifi, Also if i tried to search for a package i keep getting `connect ETIMEDOUT xx.xx.xxx.xx:xxx` with a different IP each time.

Comment: It really does sound like you are encountering some kind of firewall or web proxy that is interfering with traffic. If you are on a managed network (office, school campus...) you may want to ask whoever runs the network if they can accommodate you.

Comment: @DanLowe i use `SimpleDNSCrypt` software, And the `Firewall` is turned on, I tried to turn both of them `Off` and try again but didn't work, If that helps.

Comment: @DanLowe It happened to work for ~15s then returned to the first error.